# Population-level data with small n's

Tags: population, small-area-estimation

I have population data (not sample data) and I'm looking at incidence over time in the population.  I have small n's (for the incidence and for the overall population).  For example, I have an incidence of 9, occurring in a population of about 40,000. Because I am dealing with small n's, would it be appropriate to use confidence intervals and trend analysis, even though I am not actually working with a sample?

Comment: Are your study conclusions going to be limited to what happened *just to this population* and *only for this time interval*?  If not, then you have a sample.  Regardless, how can we advise you about what procedures to use?  You haven't told us what you're trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really dealing with population data than there is nothing to estimate, since there is no uncertanity. The event happened in the population *exactly* 9 times.

Check also: [Statistical inference when the sample "is" the population](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/statistical-inference-when-the-sample-is-the-population) and [What is the difference between a population and a sample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-is-the-difference-between-a-population-and-a-sample) (as *@whuber* may be right that you may be misinterpreting your sample as population).