# Sample vs Population: what is correct?

Tags: sample

I have the data from several countries (including my country). My problem is to compare the data from "population" (all countries) with data from my country, to answer the question: is my country a representative sample from the population, in other words, are we "similar"? So, I generate the confidence intervals from the sample data (my country data), and want to know, if they contain the population parameter. The question is the following: as population parameter, should I consider the value for all countries, or the value for all countries exluding my country?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a population and a sample?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-is-the-difference-between-a-population-and-a-sample) TLDR; it can be either population or sample depending on your objectives and the question cannot be answered without further context. Btw for population data you do not use confidence intervals.

Comment: What I meant, the population "all countries" consists of "my country" and "not my country". And, if I believe that "my country" is a representative sample from "all countries", then CIs for mean constructed on the basis of "my country"-data should cover the "true mean" of "all countries", is it right?